# How to simulate a slow printer in Windows XP?

Tags: vb6, printing, windows-xp

To test printing in a Visual Basic Project I need to simulate a SLOW printer,
how can I do that?

Comment: Please explain why you want to do that. Windows queues print jobs, so an application has no way of noticing that the printer is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Fax modems are pretty slow, and you should be able to find a print-to-fax driver somewhere. But since Windows spools print jobs, your application won't notice that the printer device is slow.

Comment: Print spooling can be switched off in the printer settings, on the "Advanced" page, setting "print directly to the printer".

Answer (score 0):

There's no better simulation than the real thing.  I can suggest several models I have personal experience with that would help with your simulation.